# Show that $f(x,y)=x+y$ is a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show a function $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=x+y$    is Lipschitz with respect to Euclidean distance. I tried to prove but I am stuck. I tried to the below:

Let $(x,y), (x',y')\in \mathbb R^2$. $$|f(x,y)-f(x',y')|=|(x+y)-(x'+y')|=|(x-x')+(y-y')|\leq|x-x'|+|y-y'|$$

I'm stuck here. How can I derive $f$ is Lipschitz?

Comment: Then you have done since the RHS is $\|(x,y)-(x',y')\|_{1}$ (the $p-$norm with $p=1$).

Comment: @Surb I forgot to mention that I was working in 2-norm (Euclidean norm). Is it also possible to derive f is Lipschitz in 2-norm?

Comment: @whwjddnjs $$\left\| \binom{a}{b}\right \|_{\ell^1} = \binom{|a|}{|b|} \cdot \binom{1}{1} \le \sqrt 2 \left\| \binom{a}{b} \right\|_{\ell^2}$$more generally all norms in a finite dimensional space are equivalent

Comment: Another way: $f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$. Write down $f(x,y)-f(x',y')$ and use [CS inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: @whwjddnjs: All norms in $\mathbb R^2$ are equivalents. Therefore, proving Lipschitz for one norms is equivalent than to prove lipschitz for all norms.

Answer (score 1):

**A very broad hint, but not a complete answer**

You need to show that there's a number $M$ with a special property: if $d(A, B) = s$, then $d(f(A), f(B)) < Ms$.

In your case, $A = (x, y)$ and $B = (x', y')$, so what is $s$? Assuming you're using the standard metric,
$$
s = \sqrt{(x' - x)^2 + (y' - y)^2}.
$$
Now the question becomes "Can you find a number $M$ with the property that
$$
|x-x'| + |y - y'| < M  \sqrt{(x' - x)^2 + (y' - y)^2},
$$
regardless of the values of $x, y, x', y'$?"

It's usually easiest to do this by squaring both sides, so you need to show that
$$
(x-x')^2 + (y - y')^2 + |2(x-x')(y-y')| < M^2  \left( (x' - x)^2 + (y' - y)^2 \right)
$$
If you picked $M = 1$, you'd get lots of cancellation between the left and right-hand sides, but you'd be left with trying to show that

$$
|2(x-x')(y-y')| < 0,
$$

which just isn't going to work out. Instead, you could try $M = 2$ (after all, YOU get to pick $M$!). Then you'd end up needing to show that

$$
|2(x-x')(y-y')| < (x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2,
$$
which feels a little more plausible. If you go to $M = 3$, you get something even easier to prove....give it a shot.

Comment: Lipschitz continuity is definied with non-strict inequality, so $M=2$ works just perfect.

Comment: I couldn't remember which it was, but if $M$ works for non-strict, then $M+1$ will work for strict, so it doesn't make a whole lot of difference.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z \in \{x,y\}$. Then $$|z-z'| = \sqrt{(z-z')^2} \leq \sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2} = \|(x,y)-(x',y')\|,$$ so $|f(x,y)-f(x',y')| \leq 2\|(x,y)-(x',y')\|$.